# Clean Architecture - How to pass request towards inner, domain level, Use Cases?

Tags: php, clean-architecture

Use Case Interactor:

[image: Use Case Interactor]

We can see it in this picture how does a request cross the layers until it reaches the **Use Case Interactor**. 
How does the controller pass the request towards the Use Case Interactor? By the request i mean the data from the user ( maybe a form ) 
I understand that the Input Port is an interface, but how do you pass data across it towards Use Case Interactor? 
Also, does every Use Case **has it's own** Input Port? If so, that doesn't make much sense, why not just use the Use Case as a reference in controller instead of adding a layer of abstraction with an interface. I mean what is the point? The layer in which controller resides knows about the layer where Use Case is located.
What i mean by this is the following:
If i have a class: `AddUserUseCase`, does that class need to have it's own input port (interface): `AddUserInputPort`. Or can we make something more generic, like `UserInputPort` and then have all `UserUseCases` implement that?

Comment: If this is a general question about software architecture, [softwareengineering.se] might be a better place to ask. If you're asking about code for a specific application using a particular MVC framework, you should add a tag for the framework and show the code you're having trouble with. But as currently written, this seems too broad and/or opinion-based for SO.

Answer (score 0):

The answer pretty much depends on the size and the complexity of your application. In a small and simple application you may instanciate the use case interactor directly in the controller and pass the request model directly through method call. 
In a bigger application your use case interactor may have some dependencies and you may want to benefit from dependency injection frameworks and let the use case interactor passed to the controller. This decision as well as testability of the controller may drive you towards separate interface per use case interactor.

For a more detailed discussion of these aspects pls refer to my blog post: http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Controller-Presenter/